# SetInterval won't stop running

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a function that uses setInterval, and it keeps running and it doesn't want to stop. The code I wrote is

```
let findGrid = setInterval(function () {
    if (grid == null) {
        grid = $('#QuickEntryGrid').getKendoGrid();
    }
    else {
        clearFindGrid;
        console.log("Found Grid");
        console.log(grid.dataSource.view());
    }
}, 100);

let clearFindGrid = function () {
    clearInterval(findGrid);
};

if (grid != null) {
    grid.setOptions({
        width: (newInnerVerticalWidth - 2) + "px"
    });
    $("#QuickEntryGrid").find("table").on("keydown", onGridKeydown);
}
```

It keeps hitting the console.log(grid.dataSource.view());

Comment: You've to call `clearFindGrid` function in the `else` block, currently you just refer it.

Comment: @Teemu, so i wrote this wrong then. Where should my clearFindGrid function go then? Once the grid is no longer null then I need the setInterval to stop

Comment: No, you didn't write it wrong, except the function call is missing, just add`()` after `clearFindGrid`.

Comment: @Teemu, yep, that fixed it thanks for pointing that out

Comment: write your function `clearFindGrid ` as `clearFindGrid()` to call the function.

Comment: Chris, think for a minute about the difference between `let f = clearFindGrid;` and `let g = clearFindGrid();` — both are valid JS, but the first assigns the _function_ to `f` and the second assigns the result of _calling_ the function to `g`

Answer (score 1):

You must call the funcion with the brakets `clearFindGrid()`